# Can't get the latest value from JSON in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode

I want to get the value from JSON in Xcode (Objective-C).
But if I change the value and build the app again, the value isn't changed.

What I tried is

1. Set the value to "1" and build the app (at the first time)
   -> I can get "1".
2. Set the value from "1" to "0" and build the app (2nd time)
   -> I can still get "1".
3. Delete the app from iPhone once and build the app again
   -> I can get "0".

Why can't I get latest value from JSON?

The code:

```
-(int)getJsonValue{

    Reachability* curReach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];

    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    if (netStatus == NotReachable) {
        // Disconnect
        _jsonValue = 0;

    } else {
        // Connect (Always through here)

        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:pathReview];
        NSURLSessionConfiguration* config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        NSURLSession* session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

        NSURLSessionDataTask* task =
        [session dataTaskWithURL:url
               completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                   id jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

                   if ([jsonData isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
                       NSMutableArray *objects = [NSMutableArray array];
                       objects = jsonData;

                       _jsonValue = [[objects objectAtIndex:0] intValue];


                   }

                   dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);

               }];
        [task resume];

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    }

    return _jsonValue;
}
```

Comment: Where are you hosting the file you are pulling? Are you updating the file and then immediately trying the app? It could be an issue with the server you are hosting the file on not actually serving the updated file when you expect it to. I've seen a similar issue with hosting things on Amazon S3 where it can hold on to cached files for a certain amount of time before actually serving up the new file

Comment: I changed the value with Coda and checked value on device immediately and after 24 hour. But not still changed. On the other app, I could pull latest value immediately.

Comment: you can't return value while you have used block inside method. you need to declare method with block .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return value through block because you have used block inside function.

```
-(void)getJsonValueWithCallback:(void(^)(NSInteger jsonValue ))callback{
    if (netStatus == NotReachable) {
        callback(0);
    }
    else{
        callback(1);
    }
}
```

**Calling**

```
[self getJsonValueWithCallback:^(NSInteger jsonValue) {
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)jsonValue);
        //
    }];
```